# Фабрика фабрик - как правильно

Tags: python, шаблоны-проектирования

В задачах обработки данных все рутинно. Получили пакет (или письмо), прочитали файл(ы), обработали файлы, создали отчет нужного типав зависимости  от пришедшего набора файлов (например xlsx-файл), отформатировали отчет, отправили результирующий файл назад. Вот для такой задачи соорудил я абстрактный класс:

```
from pathlib import Path

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod   # , abstractproperty


class IZI_report(ABC):
"""Class for reports."""

def __init__(self,  path_to_files_folder: Path):
    self.path_to_files_folder = path_to_files_folder
    self.response = {             # dict_to_return
        "exit_is_ok": False,
        "exit_message": "",
         # ...
     }

@abstractmethod
def files_reading(self, path_to_files_folder):
    ...

@abstractmethod
def data_processing(self, **pd_files):
    ...

@abstractmethod
def excel_writer(self, path_to_files_folder, client_name, files):
    ...

@abstractmethod
def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_attach):
    ...
```

Здесь предполагается, что предварительно файл(ы) уже лежат в папке `file_to_attach`. Но это не так важно.
И все бы ничего, только вот форматирование эксель файлов в среде виндовс родной библиотекой бывает до 10 раз быстрее, чем "универсальной", не зависящей от операционной системы.  Поэтому каждая конкретная реализация метода  `excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_attach)` выглядит у меня примерно так:

```
def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_attach):

    def o_excel_file_formatting(file_to_attach):
        # используем медленный универсальный модуль
        ...


    def w_excel_file_formatting(file_to_attach):
        # используем быстрый windows-модуль
        ...

   
    return (w_excel_file_formatting if current_os_is_win else o_excel_file_formatting)(file_to_attach)
```

Но мне это не казалось красивым. Поскольку в каждом конкретном методе повторялись написанные вспомогательные функции, обеспечивающие форматирование. Например `o_header_wrap_and_size` или `o_search_and_colorise`. Думаю по названию понятно чем они занимаются.  Если их везде дублировать, то нарушается принцип **DRY**.
Можно было бы включить эти вспомогательные мелкие функции прямо в абстрактный класс, но это как то нарушает "соразмерность" методов  в абстрактном классе.
А делать вместо метода абстрактного класса целую фабрику классов как-то боязно и громоздко.
Вопрос - какие стандартные правила создания методов в таких случаях считаются правильными, "питонячими"?
Похоже здесь подойдет вложенный класс, нет?
Однако мнения о приемлемости вложенных (*inner, nested*)  классов разделились. Есть [против](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376127/is-it-a-good-practice-to-make-nested-class-in-python), есть и [за](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719705/what-is-the-purpose-of-pythons-inner-classes).
Есть ли какие то рекомендации на этот счет?

Comment: Как вариант, подмена имен `monkey patching` в самом начале скрипта.

Comment: ну пока что я так и делаю ):      (w_excel_file_formatting if current_os_is_win else o_excel_file_formatting)(file_to_attach)

Comment: Увидеть бы различия в этих двух методах. Там ведь не только один вызов отличается?

Comment: @user207200  редставьте проверку данных по разным направлениям работы склада Amazon. Один набор файлов для проверки возвратов на склад и свой ответный отчет в формате xlsx, другой - для проверки правильности оплаты взятой за доставку согласно весу. Но в результате - снова отчет xlsx файл с другими колонками и другим форматированием. Так что они РАЗНЫЕ совсем, но везде форматируется шапка и везде по разному подкрашиваются нужные заголовки.  Как то так

Comment: Может неверно понял задачу, но есть ощущение, что тут может помочь композиция. Ты делаешь базовый класс `ExcelFormatter`, реализуешь на его основе `WindowsExcelFormatter` и `GenericExcelFormatter`. Они должны предоставлять одинаковый API, конечно же. В таком случае ты выделяешь низкоуровневую логику форматирования из класса репортов, вызывая методы ExcelFormatter'a, а сам ExcelFormatter задаёшь при инициализации репортера, определив систему.

Comment: @ДмитрийКалинников
Я в итоге так и сделал.
Можешь оформить как ответ если хочешь  -  отмечу как решение )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть ощущение, что тут может помочь композиция.
Ты делаешь базовый класс `ExcelFormatter`, реализуешь на его основе `WindowsExcelFormatter` и `GenericExcelFormatter`. Они должны предоставлять одинаковый API, конечно же.

В таком случае ты выделяешь низкоуровневую логику форматирования из класса репортов, вызывая методы базового `ExcelFormatter`, а инстанс и настройки `ExcelFormatter` задаёшь при инициализации репортера, определив систему.

Answer (score 0):

Я пошел по пути создания вложенных классов и создал явную "фабрику" прямо внутри `__init__`.
Надеюсь такая реализация не слишком вычурная.  Меня в конце концов,  такое решение устроило:  повторяющиеся функции описаны внутри класса, так что их переписывать в каждой реализации не нужно.  А создание класса зависящего от типа ОС выписано явно.  Так что "скрытых" последствий нет.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys
  
from copy import copy   # , deepcopy

from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
import openpyxl as opx

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod   # , abstractproperty


import win32com.client


class IZI_report(ABC):
    """Class for reports."""

    def __init__(self,  path_to_files_folder: Path):
        print('IZI_report(ABC) init')
        self.current_os_is_win = sys.platform in ['win32', 'cygwin'] and os.name == "nt"
        if self.current_os_is_win:
            print('win32com.client')
            import win32com.client
        if self.current_os_is_win:
            self.xlsx_formater = self.Windows_excel_file_formatting()
        else:
            self.xlsx_formater = self.Common_excel_file_formatting()

        self.path_to_files_folder = path_to_files_folder

        self.response = {           # dict_to_return
            "exit_is_ok": False,
            "exit_message": "",
            "files": dict(),
            'zip_path': None,
        }

    @ abstractmethod
    def files_reading(self, path_to_files_folder):
        ...

    @ abstractmethod
    def data_processing(self, **pd_files):
        ...

    @ abstractmethod
    def excel_writer(self, path_to_files_folder, client_name, files):
        ...

    class Windows_excel_file_formatting(ABC):

        def search_and_colorise(self, work_sheet, searched_texts_list, color=4):
            """"""
            if type(searched_texts_list) is str:
                raise Exception('list of str expected!')
            for seached in searched_texts_list:
                work_sheet.Cells.Find(seached).Interior.ColorIndex = color

        def header_wrap_and_size(self, ws, size):
            """"""
            ws.Rows('1:1').WrapText = True
            ws.Columns(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns).ColumnWidth = size
            ws.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.AutoFit()

        @ abstractmethod
        def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_format):
            ...

    class Common_excel_file_formatting(ABC):
        """Format xlsx file."""

        def search_and_colorise(self, work_sheet, searched_texts_list, color='EE1111'):
            """Renewed."""
            if type(searched_texts_list) is str:
                raise Exception('list of str expected!')
            # openpx style
            fill_color = PatternFill(start_color=color,
                                     end_color=color,
                                     fill_type='solid')
            for searched in searched_texts_list:
                for j in range(1, work_sheet.max_column + 1):
                    print(work_sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value)
                    if work_sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value:
                        if work_sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).value.find(searched) >= 0:
                            work_sheet.cell(row=1, column=j).fill = fill_color

        def header_wrap_and_size(self, ws, size):
            """Renewed."""
            for j in range(1, ws.max_column + 1):
                ws.cell(row=1, column=j).alignment = \
                    opx.styles.Alignment(
                    horizontal='center',  # 'general',
                    vertical='bottom',
                    text_rotation=0,
                    wrap_text=True,
                    shrink_to_fit=False,
                    indent=0)
                ws.column_dimensions[opx.utils.cell.get_column_letter(j)].width = size

        @ abstractmethod
        def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_format):
            ...
```

В тоже время такая реализация несколько, я бы сказал, "некрасивая" )) Ведь для того, чтобы создать класс надо внутри класса наследоваться от родителя с явным указанием имени абстрактного класса.  Вот так:
`class Windows_excel_file_formatting(IZI_report.Windows_excel_file_formatting)`
Итого, работает, но хотелось бы чего то более изящного.

Пример создания тестового класса, прямо читающего файл с диска с последующей его разметкой описаной в абстрактном классе функцией `search_and_colorise` ...

```
class Test(IZI_report):

    def __init__(self, path: Path):
        super().__init__(path)
        self.SNAPSHOTS_PATTERNS = ["rec", "adj", "rei"]
        self.separators = " _-"

    def files_reading(self, path_to_files_folder):
        ...

    def data_processing(self, **pd_files):
        ...

    def excel_writer(self, path_to_files_folder, client_name, files):
        ...

    class Windows_excel_file_formatting(IZI_report.Windows_excel_file_formatting):

        def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_format):
            print('excel_file_formatting')
            Excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
            print(1)
            wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "sh1.xlsx"))
            print(2)
            ws_rec = wb.Worksheets("Аркуш1")
            print("---- before =====")
            self.search_and_colorise(ws_rec, ("01_", '10_', '20_'))
            wb.Save()
            print(3)
            wb.Close()
            Excel.Application.Quit()
            Excel.Quit()

    class Common_excel_file_formatting():
        """Format xlsx file."""

        def excel_file_formatting(self, file_to_format):
            wb = opx.load_workbook("sh1.xlsx")
            ws_rec = wb["Sheet01"]


path_to = Path("nothng.txt")
zz = Test(path_to)
zz.xlsx_formater.excel_file_formatting('ff')
```

Все работает, но как то не изящно что ли,  с излишним расходованием ресурсов во время создания класса.
Буду признателен за подсказки!